# Increase delay between each photo in photo screensaver

Tags: windows-7, windows, screensaver

I've set my screensaver to "Photos". How can I increase the delay from "slow" when the photo changes while screensaver is running? This does not seem possible in Control Panel. Can this possibly can be configured via the registry?

Comment: The Photos screen saver settings has a slide show speed.  Is this not sufficient?

Comment: @Steven apologies for ambiguity, question updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, the built-in Photos screensaver has only three speed settings and are stored in the following registry key.

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows Photo Viewer\Slideshow\Screensaver

The DWORD value Speed corresponds to: 0 = Slow, 1 = Medium, 2 = Fast.  ***If the value is anything else, the settings window (and probably the screen saver itself) will load with Medium.***

These are the limitations of the screen saver.  If you want a slower speed, you will have to find another screen saver with additional customizations.

Comment: I don't understand how does changing the DWORD value decrease the speed as "If the value is anything else, the settings Window will load with Medium." ?

Comment: Edited answer (as I didn't understand your question initially).  Basically, you have three speed settings.  Changing the registry to another value cannot decrease the speed further.